# Is it possible that a Javascript WebSocket could connect before the `open` event listener is added, so you would then miss the event?

Tags: websocket

This seems to be the canonical way to open a browser-side websocket and then wait for the `open` event...

```
// Create WebSocket connection.
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

// Connection opened
socket.addEventListener('open', (event) => {
  socket.send('Hello Server!');
});
```

According to the [standard](https://websockets.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-websocket-websocket%E2%91%A0)...

```
socket = new WebSocket(url [, protocols ])

   Creates a new WebSocket object, immediately establishing the associated WebSocket connection.
```

If the `new` *immediately* starts establishing the connection, is it possible on a very fast link (like, say, to localhost?) that the connection could be established and the `open` event fired before the line adding the listener is reached? And then the event would be missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per a note in section 4 of the [WebSockets Standard](https://websockets.spec.whatwg.org/#feedback-from-the-protocol):

> Since the algorithm above is queued as a task, there is no race condition between the WebSocket connection being established and the script setting up an event listener for the open event.

Sometimes implementations fail to adhere to standards, so I tested this locally in Firefox 111.0.1 with the following:

```
let open_was_caught=false;

const socket=new WebSocket(socket_url);

socket.addEventListener(
   "open",
   ()=>{open_was_caught=true;}
);

if(socket.readyState==WebSocket.OPEN && !open_was_caught)
{
   console.err("Race condition exists!");
}
```

This test yielded no evidence of the existence of a race condition.

Comment: Does "Since the algorithm above is queued as a task" mean that the outgoing websocket connection is not actually opened until after the thread calling the `new Websocket()` returns? (Sorry, I am not a JS native speaker :)  )

Comment: The definitions of  _task_ and _event loop_ in this case are defined in the HTML standard, and I'm no expert in that! I'm reassured that the standard declares that a race condition does not exist, and I'm looking for other causes of my web socket problem. 

My guess is that the connection process is queued as a _task_, `new Websocket(socket_url)` returns, and the remainder of the script will execute before the _event loop_ begins work on the _task_. I assume this holds if you add the listener in the same script call. I wouldn't assume it would hold if you added the listener in a later call.